# Python pandas does not format first column

Tags: python, pandas

I write currently a python script which splits data from a excel file into different tables and stores the data in a new excel file. Everything works so far, but I discovered a problem I do not really understand. In the end of my script I want to format the columns of my destination excel file. What I do is, that I calculate the maximum size of each column and save it as in a variable followed by a "set_column" function call such as follows:

```
format = writer.book.add_format({'text_wrap': True, 'align': 'left', 'valign': 'top'})
for column in df:
  writer.sheets[sheet_name].set_column(idx, idx, col_len, format)
```

It works perfect for each column, but the first. In the first column I have the date written in a user defined format. Every other column works perfectly.

If I debug and check if also the first column is formatted in the loop, then yes it is. I do not really understand the misbehavior. Could someone please help?

Thanks a lot!
SkiD

Answer (score 1):

personally I use `reset_index()` to add the index as a column and use the `index=False` argument when using `.to_excel()`, this should then work with your column formatting.

Example:

```
df.reset_index()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(('file_name.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Example Sheet', index=False)
```

Note:
this wont work for Multi indexed dataframes

You can also try

```
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter
```

such as

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for your answer, but I don't really understand, how this should help with the wrong formatting of the first column. Currently I do not have used the `reset_index()` function, but I tried and it didn't solve the problem. `index=False` was already set.

Comment: the work around relies on the fact that the inbuilt formatting only applies to the index column so by using `.reset_index()` you can make the index a column in the data frame like any other, once this is done the `index=False` argument in the `.to_excel()` call stops the new index column being included in the excel file, hope that is clear if not I'll add an example to my answer